# Fast replacing characters in a string and checking if a substring is a palindrome

Tags: python, algorithm

A line is received at the input to the program, the length of which is not more than 10^5.

After this comes a lot of instructions of two types:

```
set l r c (l - start of substring, r - end of substring, c - character to replace all substring characters)

ask l r (l - start of substring, r - end of substring)

1 ⩽ l ⩽ r ⩽ string length
```

`Set` command, replaces all substring characters with the given character. And the `ask` command must check if the substring is a palindrome.

For example, if the program receives such data at the input

```
5 5 - line length and number of commands
abcde
ask 1 5
set 2 4 z
ask 2 4
set 5 5 a
ask 5 5
```

Then in response she will print:

```
NO
YES
YES
```

My implementation is very not optimal. It works, but for too long. Tell me, please, a faster algorithm.

```
def p(s):
    for i in range(len(s)//2):
        if s[i]!=s[-1-i]:
            return False
    return True

N,Q = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
s = list(input())
for i in range(Q):
    c = input().split()
    if c[0]=='set':
        s[int(c[1])-1:int(c[2])] = [c[3]]*(int(c[2])-int(c[1])+1)
    elif c[0]=='ask': 
        if p(s[int(c[1])-1:int(c[2])]):
            print('YES')
        else:
            print('NO')
```

implementation with a separate search for all palindromes, after replacing some substring.

```
def allPalindromeSubstring(s): 
    v = {}
    pivot = 0.0
    while pivot < len(s): 
        palindromeRadius = pivot - int(pivot) 
        while ((pivot + palindromeRadius) < len(s) and 
                   (pivot - palindromeRadius) >= 0 and 
                  (s[int(pivot - palindromeRadius)] == 
                   s[int(pivot + palindromeRadius)])):
            l = int(pivot - palindromeRadius) + 1
            r = int(pivot + palindromeRadius + 1)
            if l in v:
                v[l].append(r)
            else:
                v[l] = [r]
            palindromeRadius += 1

        pivot += 0.5
    return v 

N,Q = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
s = list(input())
ps = allPalindromeSubstring(s)
for i in range(Q):
    c = input().split()
    l = int(c[1]); r = int(c[2])
    if c[0]=='set':
        s[l-1:r] = [c[3]]*(r-l+1)
        ps = allPalindromeSubstring(s)
    elif c[0]=='ask':
        b = True
        if l in ps:
            for j in ps[l]:
                if r<=j:
                    print('YES')
                    b = False
                    break  
        if b:
            print('NO')
```

Comment: This sounds like a coding competition question. The whole point of these is for you to think outside the box and look for a trick. Please don't ask us to do it for you.

Comment: I just ask, suggest a possible approach to the problem. Not code, not even a whole algorithm, but just possible methods that I can use.

Comment: Added implementation with a separate search for all palindromes, after replacing some substring. Still running too slow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough data to time my new code. But this must be faster than yours :)

```
import numpy as np
from math import ceil


N, Q = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
s = np.asarray(list(input()), dtype="unicode")
for i in range(Q):
    c = input().split()
    if c[0] == 'set':
        s[int(c[1]) - 1:int(c[2])] = c[3]
    elif c[0] == 'ask':
        st, ed = int(c[1]) - 1, int(c[2]) - 1
        if np.array_equal(s[st:st+ceil((ed-st)/2)+1], s[ed:st+ceil((ed-st)/2)-1:-1]):
            print('YES')
        else:
            print('NO')
```